# How to find Moment of Inertia at a different axis?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation, moment-of-inertia

So I have a solid disk:
m = 2.98 kg
r = 0.2 m
and an axis in the - and + z direction (in unit vector form, the k dimension)

And I have to find the Moment of Inertia of the disk if the axis is at point (0.5, 0), assuming the center of the disk is at the origin.

How would I go about solving this?
Thank you!

P.S. How would I go around solving for any shape at any point, in clear language?

Comment: You are not even stating the problem sufficiently for it to be solved. You need to specify not just where the axis is, but also the orientation of the axes. Look up parallel axis theorem and perpendicular axis theorem if you want to find cheaper ways to do things.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ooptions

You can either perferom the full integral (the definition of moment of inertia), or you can calculate it when it is aligned and then perform a rotation